# call controller using ajax failing to find controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to call a controller via ajax without to much luck.
I have create this in my view

```
    <input type="submit" id="preview-email" value="Preview Email" />

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#preview-email").click(function () {
        var p = { "email": "1223" };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/BusinessController/PreviewEmail',
            type: "POST",
            data: p,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

My controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PreviewEmail(string email)
    {
      //  string d = ViewData["editor"].ToString();
        string e = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(email);
        EmailModel model = new EmailModel() { EmailBody = e };
        return PartialView("_PreviewEmail", model);
    }
```

Turning on fiddler is telling me that its a 500 error. What have I done wrong? I've placed a breakpoint on my controller however it doesnt get that far

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your URL should be:

'/Business/PreviewEmail'

instead of:

'/BusinessController/PreviewEmail'

However, the recommended practice for building URLs is to use your routes:

Url.Action("PreviewEmail", "Business")

BTW, you have another problem in your code.  By setting "application/json" as your contentType, MVC will expect a JSON string.  However, when you assign a JavaScript object to the data property of $.ajax(), jQuery will serialize the value to this:

email=1223

So you'll want to assign a string to the data property instead by doing this:

var p = '{ "email": "1223" }';

Answer (score 0):

`@Url.Action` doesn't work inside the JS file. What if my call to `Controller/Action` is inside JS file?

For now I'm, retrieving the `location.href` and then replacing the Action name. 
(This may not be a wise thing to do)